# Are election primary votes intended to count towards your Q&A votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, vote-count

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/i-cant-undo-or-change-my-vote-in-the-primary-election-phase), Kobi pointed out that primary votes on moderator election candidates count toward your total votes on SO (outside of the election), a behavior which I tested and confirmed.

Is this intended? If so, does a primary candidate vote count as a question vote, answer vote, or neither? (I ask this with specific regards to the Electorate badge.)

Comment: I even got the Critic badge on SU when I downvoted someone in the primary.

Comment: Isn't this kinda like paying for votes then? You have a secondary incentive to vote on people than just ... you know ... voting on them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These votes will no longer appear on your profile or used in any of the current badge grant calculations.

Comment: This has an interesting side-effect on my SO profile: http://i.imgur.com/I4arE.png

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

This answer was correct at the time, but was made obsolete by code changes on Feb 5th, 2011.

---

According to ChrisF and Yi Jiang, the mod candidates appear as *questions* in the API.  So votes would supposedly count as question votes (for now).

Reference: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/475070#475070

Comment: Yes, you can confirm this by looking at the election nominations post in the `/questions` route in the API - http://api.programmers.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/39586. Trying to do the same in `/answers/` will return no results. Other titbits you can glean from that result is that they are CW (quite obvious) and any direct links to them, like say http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/39586 will always return 404, which is probably why their view count is 0