# Please stop counting Moderator Election Votes as part of our profile

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, election, vote-count

I was most dismayed to see that votes I made for moderator candidates were being added to my profile stats.

It does not seem right that these votes should count the way question and answer votes do. ([Kobi, and others, seem to agree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/i-cant-undo-or-change-my-vote-in-the-primary-election-phase).)

This also works against those of us who are working to an up/down ratio, or [striving for the Electorate badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/are-election-primary-votes-intended-to-count-towards-your-qa-votes).

Please remove these votes from the normal SO tallies and statistics.

Comment: It actually helps your progress to the Electorate badge as the nominations are *questions* rather than answers.

Comment: @ChrisF:  Do you have a source/reference for that?   You could answer [Jason Plank's question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76622/).  Seems like the votes would be for **answers** to the **question**, "Who shall be the next moderators?" :D     But, even if they helped towards the electorate badge, it doesn't seem proper to count those votes in our SO profile/stats.

Comment: @Brock yes Yi Jiang (who wrote the election page) told me in chat - http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/475070#475070 - "Technically speaking they are questions - I looked them up using the API"

Comment: I really don't understand why this would be a problem. I'm quite shocked that your rep/badges are more important to you than who is going to help moderating the site.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: Nowhere did I state that valued badges more than moderators (Not that that isn't a very valid and logical stance on stackexchange sites).  I merely linked to others (at least six) who had that question.  Personally, I was more annoyed that my up/down ratio got hammered by an unexpected side-effect.

Comment: I see but really does it matter that much?

Comment: @Octavian Damiean: No, obviously this is not an earth shattering issue.  Just an annoyance and a question.  I don't see that I treated it otherwise. Although, 10 upvotes here, and several upvotes elsewhere, suggest that I'm not the only one annoyed/curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These votes will no longer appear on your profile or used in any of the current badge grant calculations.