# Reordering votes in final election phase?

Tags: support, election

I've cast a vote in the moderator election, and I can't figure out how to uncast or reorder it.

I want to vote for a candidate that I've already voted for, but I would like to place them in a different choice slot than what I've currently placed them in.

Pretty sure this is not a dupe of these questions because the phase works differently:

- [Locking the votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79632/locking-the-votes)
- [I can't undo or change my vote in the primary election phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/i-cant-undo-or-change-my-vote-in-the-primary-election-phase)

Comment: I had no intention to vote but just marked someone as "2nd choice" with a stray mouse click.  I can't undo it.  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Rob: I don't remember marking this a feature request.  Weird.

Comment: @RobN: I've reworded my question.  You can open yours as a feature request and now this probably wouldn't be a dupe of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move your votes around at will.  But you cannot remove the last vote altogether. So, once you cast one or more votes, you will always have at least one vote cast.

[It has been pointed out that you can indeed erase all but one of your votes using the following method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112923/we-need-ability-to-undo-election-votes/112925#112925):

> You can only apply one of your votes at a time to any singular one individual. If, for whatever reason, you want to cancel your secondary or tertiary votes (rather than move them to someone else), vote for one of the candidates you do want to vote for as that slot, then reassert the correct slot.
>
> For example, if you voted A as 1, and B as 2, to simply cancel 2, vote A as 2 then as 1. This will remove your 2nd vote until you return to cast it anew.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can remove all but one vote by changing your vote for one candidate per [Grace Note's instructions here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112923/we-need-ability-to-undo-election-votes/112925#112925).

Comment: @KevinVermeer thanks for pointing that out.