# We need ability to undo election votes

Tags: feature-request, election, undo

I followed a link to the Stack Overflow moderator election.  I have not voted in these before and I am unfamiliar with the page layout and process.  I accidentally hit the mouse while over a "2nd choice" button on one of the candidates.  I had no intention to vote, but I don't see  a way to undo it.  My first instinct was clicking on the button again, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try clicking on "second choice" for another candidate, who you actually want to be your second choice?

Comment: No, because I have no intention to vote at all.  I have no opinion in the matter.

Comment: This has finally been implemented with the revamp of the election UI: see [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979).

Answer (score 8):

You can only apply one of your votes at a time to any singular one individual. If, for whatever reason, you want to cancel your secondary or tertiary votes (rather than move them to someone else), vote for one of the candidates you *do* want to vote for as that slot, then reassert the correct slot.

For example, if you voted A as 1, and B as 2, to simply cancel 2, vote A as 2 then as 1. This will remove your 2nd vote until you return to cast it anew.

Comment: We need to cancel the popup that says "You have cast all of your votes" when people do that, it's rather confusing.

Comment: @Tim Well, at that time, you *have* cast all of your votes. It's just a matter of rearranging them afterwards, or retracting.

Comment: Well, if they're taking one away from someone and giving it to someone else, then they _just_ cast all of their votes. "Your vote has been adjusted" might be better in that case. Probably a feature request for the next election :) My first vote in this election is locked (I'm not going to change it), but the other two are damn hard. I've reproduced this.

Comment: In my question I said "I had no intention to vote".  I have no opinion about who should be a moderator, and I don't want to spend the time reading the statements.  My vote is "noise" in the system, and I want to go back to having zero votes cast.

Comment: @RobN Well, in *that* case, you can't actually retract, to my knowledge. There's still 3 days of elections - you could consider examining the candidates to transform this into an informed decision. If ultimately there is no choice, I'll see what I can find out about something that can be done.

Comment: See [retract the last choice with these steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310796/3404097).