# Why was there a 10 vote discrepancy in the last Stack Overflow election?

Tags: support, election

This hardly makes or breaks an election, but the vote count total for the Stack Overflow election appears to be off. On the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2), it says (emphasis mine):

> 72,908 voters were eligible, 45,177 visited the site during the election, 17,866 visited the election page, and **5,004 voted**

But the [election ballot file](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/2) only contains 4,994 ballots: OpenSTV only reads 4,994 ballots, and there are only 4,994 ballot lines.

Why is this?

---

Apparently this was silently fixed. Yay! Would still like to understand what happened, though.

Comment: A guess: the ballot data contains no votes that didn't specify a first choice, so perhaps [users who had a second or third choice but no first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112923/we-need-ability-to-undo-election-votes) had their votes ignored. I think such a ballot could strictly be considered invalid, even if it might reasonably be interpreted by moving their second/third choices up.

Comment: @Cleanupcareer-development We were [just talking about that in Programmers chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3180488#3180488), and found those are counted: of the people who used all three votes, Anna only got 756 first-choice votes; but if you count the people who only used one or two votes, her first choice total goes up to 771, which is what OpenSTV reports in Round 1.

Comment: Another guess: 10 voters went awol at some point. Deleted / merged accounts, temp suspensions.

Comment: The election page apparently changed its mind.

Comment: *"Why was there a 10 vote discrepancy in the last Stack Overflow election?"* One for each of my sock puppets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 10 missing votes were in fact from users who were deleted.  I'll make sure this is handled correctly for future elections so that the election download is always correct as of the time the election is completed.

Comment: I'll make sure we cover up carefully before we let people see the results. `</joke>`

Comment: The Bilderberg Group approves.

Comment: Even Stack Overflow accepts votes from the dead?!   o_O

Comment: Given that June 2012 SO election was 10 votes off, and July 2012 SU election 1 vote, in what way was this issue fixed? Please explain.

Answer (score 33):

> Would still like to understand what happened, though.

They fixed the election. The conspiracy is bigger than you realize. You need to meet me at th—

`<USER DISCONNECTED>`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: I can hear the black helicopters whisking Juan away. I mean, I *could* hear them if they weren't in stealth mode.