# Can I undo my second vote in the election without choosing another candidate?

Tags: support, election

In the ELL moderator election, I have three votes, but I only want to vote for one candidate. (The only one I know well enough to vote for.) For the second vote, I clicked on a candidate, but I want to undo that vote now. How can I do it without voting for someone else instead?

I've tried clicking on the vote again, but the vote remained, and a message appeared:

> You have cast your second vote, you have 1 vote remaining.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112923/21960

Comment: This has finally been implemented with the revamp of the election UI: see [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112925/21960), you can simply cast your 2nd vote on your number 1 candidate, then cast your first vote for that candidate. That should leave the #2 vote empty.